# Asking the user to input something and use Beautiful Soup to parse a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am supposed to use Beautiful Soup 4 to obtain course information off of my school's website as an exercise. I have been at this for the past few days and my code still does not work.

The first thing I ask the user is to import the course catalog abbreviation. For example, ICS is abbreviated as Information for Computer Science. Beautiful Soup 4 is supposed to list all of the courses and how many students are enrolled.

While I was able to get the input portion to work, I still have errors or the program just stops.

Question: Is there a way for Beautiful Soup to accept user input so that when the user inputs ICS, the output would be a list of all courses that are related to ICS?

Here is the code and my attempt at it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

#get input for course
course = input('Enter the course:')
#Here is the page link
BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL = f"https://www.sis.hawaii.edu/uhdad/avail.classes?i=MAN&t=202010&s={course}"


#get request and response
page_response = requests.get(BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL)
#getting Beautiful Soup to gather the html content
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
#getting course information
main = page_content.find_all(class_='parent clearfix')
main_p = "".join(str (x) for x in main)
#get the course anchor tags
main_q = BeautifulSoup(main_p, "html.parser")
courses = main.find('a', href = True)
#get each course name
#empty dictionary for course list
courses_list = []
for a in courses:
    courses_list.append(a.text)
    search = input('Enter the course title:')
for course in courses_list:
    if re.search(search, course, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(course)
```

This is the original code that was provided in Juypter Notebook

```
import requests, bs4

BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL = f"https://www.sis.hawaii.edu/uhdad/avail.classes?i=MAN&t=202010&s={course}"
#get input for course
course = input('Enter the course:')



def scrape_availability(text):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
    r = requests.get(str(BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL)  + str(course))
    rows = soup.select('.listOfClasses tr')

    for row in rows[1:]:
        columns = row.select('td')
        class_name = columns[2].contents[0]
        if len(class_name) > 1 and class_name != b'\xa0':
            print(class_name)
            print(columns[4].contents[0])
            print(columns[7].contents[0])
            print(columns[8].contents[0])
```

What's odd is that if the user saves the html file, uploads it into Juypter Notebook, and then opens the file to be read, the courses are displayed. But, for this task, the user can not save files and it must be an outright input to get the output.

Comment: *"I still have errors or the program just stops"* - A specific error is telling you what's failing and why.  Don't just give up when you see an error message.  Read and understand the message, use its information to understand and correct the problem.  So... What is the error?  Where specifically does it happen?  What are the runtime values when it happens?

Comment: @David At first it was a something not defined which made me realize that the code order was wrong. On one earlier attempt, I had the url on first before the input when it was supposed to be the other way around. The problem now is that sure that the input box has shown up but then after I type the course abbreviation, in this case it was ICS, nothing happens. It specifically happens after I input the course.

Comment: @David I know there are tutorials out there for Beautiful Soup but NONE of them are talking about what I need to do. All of the tutorials I have seen so far have this
url = 'http:// whatever it is '
and I know that is fixed which means I can't have user input. So Beautiful Soup is going to parse the url and that depends on what needs to be scraped/parsed

Comment: Now would be the time to do some debugging.  "Nothing happens" is a bit of a non-starter.  In the absense of a debugger, one thing you can you can do is add a variety of lines of output throughout the code.  You can output what your various runtime values are, output lines that indicate which code blocks have been reached, etc.  The code doesn't "just stop".  It either exits with an exception or it executes to a logical completion.  For example, each of your lines after getting the user input is creating a value.  What do each of those values end up being?

Comment: @chitown88 way earlier in the semester, I was taught the input for python which is 
testing = input('Type hi:')
and then it will work when I run this on Juypter Notebook
Now,  I need to bring the input into the url of the website but to do that, I need 
course = input('Enter the course letters:')
normally without the url, the code will just give a box and ask the user to input the course letters...
But now I need the input to be the course letters that is going to be placed in the url so the output would be the url being accessed and printing the courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is `page_content.find_all(class_='parent clearfix')` retuns and empty list `[]`. So thats the first thing you need to change. Looking at the html, you'll want to be looking for `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, tags

working off what was provided from the original code, you just need to alter a few things to flow logically:

I'll point out what I changed:

```
import requests, bs4

BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL = f"https://www.sis.hawaii.edu/uhdad/avail.classes?i=MAN&t=202010&s={course}"
#get input for course
course = input('Enter the course:')



def scrape_availability(text):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)   #<-- need to get the html text before creating a bs4 object. So I move the request (line below) before this, and also adjusted the parameter for this function.
                                     # the rest of the code is fine
    r = requests.get(str(BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL)  + str(course))
    rows = soup.select('.listOfClasses tr')

    for row in rows[1:]:
        columns = row.select('td')
        class_name = columns[2].contents[0]
        if len(class_name) > 1 and class_name != b'\xa0':
            print(class_name)
            print(columns[4].contents[0])
            print(columns[7].contents[0])
            print(columns[8].contents[0])
```

This will give you:

```
import requests, bs4

BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL = "https://www.sis.hawaii.edu/uhdad/avail.classes?i=MAN&t=202010&s="
#get input for course
course = input('Enter the course:')

url = BASE_AVAILABILITY_URL  + course

def scrape_availability(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.select('.listOfClasses tr')

    for row in rows[1:]:
        columns = row.select('td')
        class_name = columns[2].contents[0]
        if len(class_name) > 1 and class_name != b'\xa0':
            print(class_name)
            print(columns[4].contents[0])
            print(columns[7].contents[0])
            print(columns[8].contents[0])



scrape_availability(url)
```

Comment: It works! I was stuck on this for a while. I guess order matters in the code because the output was nothing when I did this so many times. Now, I just have to make the labels for how many students enrolled and seats available. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: good. I hope it makes sense. You were essentially trying to parse the html `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')` , before actually getting the html `r = requests.get(url)`. Sort of like trying to drive a car, before you start the engine.